# CSS dropdown menu positioning - slide up?

Tags: css

I have a pop-up menu system (ala superfish style) called Yt Mega Menu that is installed in a Joomla web site.  The standard configuration as with most menus is that when a menu item is hovered over, the sub-menu drops down.  For the project I am working on, I need to alter this such that the sub-menu slides up as the menu sits at the bottom of the page.

In its hidden state, the sub-menu is positioned absolutely with a left positon of -999em.  When the parent menu item is hovered over, the top is set to auto and the bottom, left, and right are all 0.

I believe I could get the desired effect if I could set the top or bottom positon for the sub-menu.  The problem is that this is dependent upon the height of the sub-menu.  How can I position this sub-menu above the primary menu item without knowing the height of the sub-menu?

UPDATE - See the menu at the bottom of the page http://www.affect4.net for the problem.  Notice the space below the menu as well as the drop-down effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your css and html? A jsfiddle would be even better for finding you a solution.

Comment: How about the "live" version ... check out the menu bar at the bottom of this page ... http://www.affect4.net ... that has the login and about menu items.

Comment: @rikkit - Sorry, copied the url from my local dev server.  Try http://www.affect4.net instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DYnrE/

Just position the sub-menus absolutely at the bottom instead of at the top.